No me funciona el metodo POST en DJANGO, siempre entra por el GET
Estoy trabajando con VSC y DJANGO creando una página web, en donde quiero hacer uso de un fomulario para solicitar datos al usuario.
Para ello creé la vista comision_create, creé el formulario, el archivo html y publiqué la url.
El error que tengo es que es que cuando ingreso a la URL se ve la página totalmente en blanco cuando me tendría que levantar el título, y en el cuerpo un formulario para ingresar datos.
Luego de analizar varias veces e ir depurando, encuentro que la vista siempre me está entrando por el else (GET), no me doy cuenta porque no entra por el método POST.
Les paso el código, ya no sé ni qué probar:
views.py
def comision_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.ComisionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("Clase:home")
    else:  # request.method == "GET"
        form = forms.ComisionForm()
    return render(request, "Clase/comision_create.html", context={"form": form})

urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'Clase'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('curso/create/', views.curso_create, name='curso_create'),
    path('comision/create/', views.comision_create, name='comision_create'),
    path('curso_list/', views.curso_list, name='curso_list'),  # Nueva URL para la lista de cursos
]

forms.py
from django import forms

from . import models

class CursoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Curso
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "nombre": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "cant_max_alumnos": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }

class ComisionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Comision
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "nombre": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "curso": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "estudiante": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "profesor": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }

comision_create.html
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block titulo %}
    Lista de Comisiones: Creación
{% endblock titulo %}

{% block contenido %}

    <!-- Inicio del contenido del formulario -->
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Fin del contenido del formulario -->
{% endblock contenido %}

models.py
from django.db import models

# Modelos creados
class Curso(models.Model):
    """Definicion de Cursos"""
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cant_max_alumnos = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=1000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Cantidad máxima de alumnos")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.nombre
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Nombre del Curso"
        verbose_name_plural = "Nombres del Curso"

class Estudiante(models.Model):
    """Definicion de clase Estudiantes"""
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Representa una instancia del modelo como una cadena de texto"""
        return self.nombre

class Profesor(models.Model):
    """Definicion de clase Profesores"""
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Representa una instancia del modelo como una cadena de texto"""
        return self.nombre
    
class Comision(models.Model):
    """Definicion de Comisiones"""
    nombre = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(unique=True)
    curso = models.ForeignKey(Curso, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    estudiante = models.ManyToManyField(Estudiante)
    profesor = models.ForeignKey(Profesor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Representa una instancia del modelo como una cadena de texto"""
        return str(self.nombre)


Al leer tu problema, al enviar un form sin definir un action esto lo tomara como un "get" y utilizara la url o path base donde esta estas apuntando al archivo "comision_create.html" en tu controlador.
modifica tu <form action="" method="post"> por algo como `
<form action="/ruta/para/crear" method="post">  o usando el name que hayas definido en tus rutas, no conozco la sintaxis de Django por eso la defino de esa manera.
Es lo que note "raro", epero que si sea y te haya solucionado el problema :)

buscando en internet parece que la forma de usar el name en el html seria
{% url 'nombre_de_la_ruta' %}
si eso es cierto entonces seria algo como:
<form action="{% url 'comision_create' %}" method="post">
